# How to parse all wikipedia's webpages?

Tags: php, wikipedia

I need to parse all the Wikipedia's webpages. How can I do that?

Could I do that through its sitemap? If so, where is Wikipedia's sitemap?

Comment: So you want to know how to rip all the content from Wikipedia without their permission?  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: why parse the entire site? Wikipedia offers the whole Database as a download, for use in mirroring, etc... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download

Comment: @Crontab He has their permission. All Wikipedia content is licensed under the [Creative Commons license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Copyrights) and the GNU FDL

Comment: I need only the titles of all wikipedia's webpages. I want to rip nothing. Thanks for the links :)

Comment: @RB - He doesn't have permission to bulk-trawl wikipedia pages... even though the content is Creative Commons

Comment: @MarkBaker I read Crontab's objection as being regarding licensing of the content, and I answered it as such. In addition, I have actually linked to Wikipedia's policy on agressive crawling in my own answer.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than parsing all the web-pages, Wikipedia allows you to [download their database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aDatabase_download). This is the preferred approach as it will generally be much quicker, as Wikipedia has over 4 million articles.

It's also fairer to Wikipedia, and won't get you blocked by them for agressive crawling. Please read [this policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aDatabase_download#Why_not_just_retrieve_data_from_wikipedia.org_at_runtime.3F)

Comment: is there a way to get only the titles of all wikipedia's italian webpages ? thanks :)

Comment: @xRobot Review the [documentation](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Database_layout). **Hint**: In particular, check out the [page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Page_table) table which has a `page_title` field.